# Style sheet not running in Docker (was working in venv) for django

Tags: python, css, django, docker

I've been pulling my hair out over this. I'm getting the following error message every time I load my page:

```
listings:20 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/static/meltexapp/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Here's my file structure:

```
meltex
-settings.py
[...]
meltexapp
-static
--meltexapp.css
-templates
--nav.html
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yaml
[...]
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import environ
import os

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-raa_)uczfns2bd8y&-vl5cg0gvyrk29%sy641kwem$809elt2g"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "meltexapp.User"
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "meltexapp",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "bootstrap5",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "meltex.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "meltex.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env("DATABASE_NAME"),
        "USER": env("DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("DATABASE_PASS"),
        "HOST": env("DATABASE_HOST"),
        "PORT": env("DB_PORT"),
    }
}


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.6
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
  --disabled-password \
  --gecos "" \
  --home "/nonexistent" \
  --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
  --no-create-home \
  --uid "${UID}" \
  appuser

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
  --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
  python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD gunicorn 'meltex.wsgi' --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - ./meltexapp/static:/app/meltexapp/static
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASS=${DATABASE_PASS}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASS}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  db-data:
```

nav.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'meltexapp/main.css' %}">
<!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/listings">Listings</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" href="/listings/add_listing">Add Listing</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" href="/listings/my_listings">My Listing</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> -->
<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight">
  <div class="page-wrap min-vw-100">
    <div class="bd-highlight">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" id="sidebar"
        style="width: 220px; height: 100vh">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32">
            <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="fs-4">MeltEx</span>
        </a>
        <hr>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="/"></use>
              </svg>
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/listings" class="nav-link text-white">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#speedometer2"></use>
              </svg>
              Listings
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/listings/my_listings" class="nav-link text-white">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#table"></use>
              </svg>
              My Listings
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/listings/add_listing" class="nav-link text-white">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
                <use xlink:href="#grid"></use>
              </svg>
              Add Listing
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle"
            id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-user ms-3 me-3" style="color: #98aac8;"></i>
            <strong>{{user.username}}</strong>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/listings/my_listings">My Listings</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/logout/">Sign out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 navbar-pad">
      <script src="/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As this was working in my virtual environment, I can only assume there's something to do with docker which I'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT - I've also noticed that even the django-admin css isn't being loaded:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/dashboard.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Not sure what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is to do with gunicorn, not exactly sure what the issue is but for some reason none of the static files load when you run this through the dockerfile:

```
CMD gunicorn 'meltex.wsgi' --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

This was the default given to me in the docker set up. I simply changed it to:

```
CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and it worked! If anyone knows why happy to have you add to this!